# Laravel Eloquent "With" filter

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Let's say I have the following setup. A `User` has many `Coments`. In my REST API I have an action `/users` where I display all the users and their comments.

I would do that like this:

```
return Response::json(User::with('comments')->get(), 200);
```

But now I only want to display a `User` in that list if it has at least one `Comment`. Something in the lines of:

```
return Response::json(User::with('comments')->whereCount('users.comments', '>', 0)->get(), 200);
```

But that obviously does not work. What is the correct way to do this in conjunction with the `with` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use in this case `has` to get only users that has at least one comment:

```
return Response::json(User::with('comments')->has('comments')->get(), 200);
```

[Reference](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations)

Comment: Also notice the `whereHas()` function in that reference if you want to add more complex conditions to it other than count.